# Call method inside a Form

Tags: c#, forms, methods

Hi I am learning C# and struggling with a Form in which a `btnCalc_click` event should call a method `calcArea` and produce the output in a `textBox1.text`

the error is in row: `textBox1.Text = calcArea.ToString();`

who can help with with the correct syntax ?

```
namespace Meetkunde
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void txbLengte_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double length = 0;
            length = double.Parse(txbLength.Text);
        }

        private void txbBreedte_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double width = 0;
            width = double.Parse(txbWidth.Text);
        }

        public double calcArea(double length, double width)
        {
            double area = 0;
            area = (length * width);
            return area;
        }

        private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {         
        }

        private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = calcArea.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: You are not passing it either double length or double width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned above - you need to pass the method the parameters as you defined them in the method.  You don't need Text Changed events for this either - plus they aren't doing anything.
Try changing your code to something like (not real sure of what exactly you named textboxes):

```
 private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       double width = Convert.ToDouble(txbBreedte.Text);//txbWidth.Text?              
       double length= Convert.ToDouble(txbLengte.Text);//txbLength.Text?
       textBox1.Text = calcArea(length, width).ToString();
  }
```

Comment: How about adding a small explanation in words of what was wrong and/or why this works so the OP has a better understanding of the solution? :-)

Answer (score -2):

```
calcArea.ToString();
```

when you are calling this, you aren't calling the function, you are referencing the function, not the return

do

```
calcArea(parameters).ToString();
```

replace parameters with what you want to calculate.

Comment: calcArea(parameters) will not work.

Comment: I think **your answer** should contain the appropriate parameters. Otherwise, it's not technically correct.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).